# Is it safe to uninstall "Surface Platform Installer"?

Tags: windows-10, uninstall, microsoft-surface-pro-3

The largest program on my computer (excluding Windows Store apps and TF2) is the Surface Platform Installer.

It doesn't show from a quick search in the Search bar. It's a folder in my `C:\` drive that has an executable, a log, and what appears to be a library of drivers and firmware.

Upon running the executable (`dpinst.exe`), it opens a wizard to install device drivers. Hitting `Next`, it displays:

[image: cannot complete installation]

It seems to be a Microsoft program, but there's no signature. Searching deeper, you can [download it from the Microsoft Download Centre](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=38826).

Is this program safe to uninstall?

**OS:** Windows 10 Pro 64-bit

**Folder path:** `C:\Program Files (x86)\SurfacePlatformInstaller`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like the drivers for your Surface Pro 3. You should keep them to avoid driver issues.

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding, it is a copy repository for drivers.

It will clear itself when you uninstall the installer and there is NO reboot needed.

(Tested with the Surface Pro 4)